# Why xAxis tickUnit didn't work in fxml file?

Tags: javafx, charts, fxml, scatter

I want to create a scatter chart by fxml file.I put the code below in my fxml file but when it done the render,it did not like I expected.Do somebody know what's going on?

```
<BorderPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.121"
      xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.ChartController">
<left>
    <ScatterChart fx:id="memoryDistribution" prefWidth="360" title="Memory Distribution">
        <xAxis>
            <NumberAxis fx:id="xAxis" label="Memory Address/k" lowerBound="0" upperBound="7" tickUnit="1.00"/>
        </xAxis>
        <yAxis>
            <NumberAxis fx:id="yAxis" label="Memory Address/k" lowerBound="1" upperBound="257" tickUnit="8.00"/>
        </yAxis>
    </ScatterChart>
</left>
```

what above code do like this:

[wrong expectation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6O9mi.png)

But what I expect is like this:

[expectation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/py6Gp.png)
the second image code:

```
    public class Main extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

    primaryStage.setTitle("Scatter Chart Sample");
    final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis(0, 8, 1);
    final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis(1, 257, 8);
    final ScatterChart<Number,Number> sc = new
            ScatterChart<>(xAxis,yAxis);
    xAxis.setLabel("Memory Address/k");
    yAxis.setLabel("Memory Address/k");
    sc.setTitle("Memory Distribution");

    XYChart.Series series1 = new XYChart.Series();
    series1.setName("job-1");
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(0.5, 5));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(1.5, 5));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(2.5, 5));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(3.5, 5));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(4.5, 5));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(5.5, 5));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(6.5, 5));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(7.5, 5));

    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(0.5, 13));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(1.5, 13));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(2.5, 13));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(3.5, 13));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(4.5, 13));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(5.5, 13));

    XYChart.Series series2 = new XYChart.Series();
    series2.setName("job-2");
    series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(0.5, 29));
    series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(1.5, 29));
    series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(2.5, 29));
    series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(3.5, 29));
    series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(4.5, 29));
    series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(5.5, 29));


    sc.getData().addAll(series1, series2);

    Scene chartScene = new Scene(sc,360,736);//best lookup

    primaryStage.setScene(chartScene);
    primaryStage.setMaximized(true);
    primaryStage.show();
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

Comment: You forgot to add the last piece of code at the bottom of your question.

Answer (score 0):

I already done my demand:the grid on,and the cell size is 256.

1. I put an any kind of Pane in the fxml,when the init start it should be render and put a blank pane in there.

   ```
       <center>
           <ScrollPane fx:id="chartPane" prefWidth="380" prefHeight="760">
           </ScrollPane>
       </center>
   ```
2. Then I write the code to init a scatter chart and put it to the above pane.
3. In the class sample.ChartController as the fxml configured,put the init code in this class,name a method initialize.

   ```
       private void initialize(){
               final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis(0,8,1);
               final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis(0,256,8);
               xAxis.setLabel("Memory Address/k");
               yAxis.setLabel("Memory Address/k");
               this.memoryDistributionChart = new ScatterChart(xAxis,yAxis);
               memoryDistributionChart.setTitle("Memory Distribution");
               memoryDistributionChart.setPrefHeight(736);
               memoryDistributionChart.setPrefWidth(360);
               chartPane.setContent(memoryDistributionChart);
       }
   ```

memoryDistributionChart is a ScatterChart,a member property.
chartPane is another member property.

finally,[the result like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6uHk.png)

Because when the main stage render,the controller initialize method should be invoked first.